# How do I restart vsftpd?

Tags: lubuntu, init.d, vsftpd

I am using Lubuntu.

I have installed vsftpd using

```
sudo apt-get install vsftpd
```

That ran all ok. However when I try to retstart the service with the following it cannot find it:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vsftpd restart
```

How do I restart the service?  I believe this command would work on ubuntu but not Lubuntu.  I am following this installation guide.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-vsftpd-ftp-service-server/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use the `service` command, like so:

```
sudo service vsftpd restart
```

The guide you're following is from 2007. Since then, the way of interacting with services has changed.

Comment: Note that the expected output of this is no output, with a 0 return code.